# Firebase edit rules granting separate abilities to different client scripts (aka. auth without a server)

Tags: javascript, security, firebase

After extensive searching (about a month) I've finally given up. However, I thought I would ask anyway since, who knows, maybe someone has done this before.

I have two js scripts, labeled, for convenience, client and server. I also have two Firebase databases: client_input and server_output. The idea is that a client writes a request to client_input, the server reads client_input -> processes the data -> writes to server_output, the client reads server_output -> renders the data to the user. This works perfectly.

The trouble is that I can't figure out how to restrict read/write capabilities based on the type of script. I tried using auth and Firebase_secret, but apparently you need a server for that. Ultimately, I would like to achieve something like the below rules:

```
client_input { ".read": "server === true", ".write": "true" }

server_output { ".read": "true", ".write": "server === true" }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create an access token using one of the firebase token generators on GitHub (https://github.com/firebase) and the Firebase secret. There are generators in a number of languages and you only need to create one once for each process, then use that to auth instead of the secret. When you do that, you can access any of the data you put in the token when you created it using the `auth` variable in the security rules.

For example, you could make two tokens - one with `{ "uid": "client" }` and one with `{ "uid": "server" }` and then in the rules reference `".write": "auth.uid === 'server'"`

Comment: It works! Using your suggestions, I was able to find a generator at [http://jsfiddle.net/katowulf/D4YL8/light/](http://jsfiddle.net/katowulf/D4YL8/light/). Then it was a simple matter of embedding the correct tokens in their respective scripts. Thanks!!!

Comment: The more official token generator is here: http://jsfiddle.net/firebase/XDXu5/embedded/result/